# Remove object from vector using its index

Tags: c++, vector

I have a class with a private member type with a getType in it, in a second class I have a vector of such class that I can add to as many classes as I want, now want I want to do is if I was given a "Type" I want to remove the whole Object from such vector by finding that object using that string and erase it. I have tried the way below but did not work, also tried iterators and templates yet none seem to work. * This is simplified for the sake of it*

```
class AutoMobile{
    private:
      string type;
    public:
        AutoMobile(string type){
            this->type = type;
        }
        string getType(){return type;}
};


class Inventory{
    private:
        vector<AutoMobile> cars;
    public:
        void removeFromInventory(string type){    // No two cars will have the same milage, type and ext
            AutoMobile car("Ford");
            cars.push_back(car);
            for( AutoMobile x : cars){
                cout<<x.getType();
            }
            for( AutoMobile x : cars){
                if(x.getType() == "Ford"){
                    cars.erase(*x); // Problem i here, this does not work!
                 }
            }
        }
};

int main(void) {
    Inventory Inven;
    Inven.removeFromInventory("Ford");
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of range `for` loop is not appropriate when you intend to remove items from a `std::vector`. Use an iterator instead.

```
vector<AutoMobile>::iterator iter = cars.begin();
for ( ; iter != cars.end(); /* Don't increment the iterator here */ )
{
   if ( iter->getType() == "Ford" )
   {
      iter = cars.erase(iter);
      // Don't increment the iterator.
   }
   else
   {
      // Increment the iterator.
      ++iter;
   }
}
```

You can simplify that block of code by using standard library functions and a lambda function.

```
cars.erase(std::remove_if(cars.begin(),
                          cars.end(),
                          [](AutoMobile const& c){return c.getType() == 
"Ford";}),
                          cars.end());
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked this way! As for when I was trying it with iterators, I had the increment in the for loop heading!!

Comment: @AliSoujoud, I remember falling into that trap. It's been a while :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `remove_if`

```
cars.erase(std::remove_if(cars.begin(), 
                          cars.end(),
                          [=](AutoMobile &x){return x.getType()==type;}),
           cars.end());
```